# How to serialize a google::protobuf::Message directly into preallocated memory?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

If I call [`ByteSizeLong`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Message.ByteSizeLong.details) on a [`google::protobuf::Message`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Message) object and I have a `char*` to a suitably sized block of preallocated memory (larger than `msg.ByteSizeLong()`), is there a way I can serialize the message directly into the memory without extra copying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
msg.SerializeToArray(buffer, bufferSize);
```

Or, provided that you really did call `ByteSizeLong()` on the message, then this is a little bit faster:

```
msg.SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray((unsigned char*)buffer);
```

The second form requires that you really did call `ByteSizeLong()` (and did not change anything afterwards) as doing so will have stored cached sizes for all sub-objects.